# Colab vs PyCharm - df.head() vs print(df.head())

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Why is df.head() (withoutprint) enough to print rows from the dataframe in Google Colab but in PyCharm, I have to actually use print(df.head()) as df.head() alone will not print any rows?

I am wondering if this could be due to different versions of Python between Google Colab and what I have in PyCharm on my local machine or if maybe it's due to a setting in PyCharm?

Not a big deal to have to use *print* in PyCharm but just asking since I am just learning Python and I was stuck for a while trying to figure out why df.head() wasn't working in PyCharm like it did in Google Colab until I figured I had to use *print*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Colab uses Jupyter notebook. If you are using a Jupyter notebook in Pycharm, it should work similarly to Google Colab. If you are using a normal Python File with `.py` extension, you have to use the print statement.

p.s. I use VS Code since it supports Jupyter notebooks directly in the editor and works similar to Google Colab.

Comment: Also PyCharm allow you to use jupyter notebooks. Just if you have a program, it will be run as Python, so the first example will just return a view. If you run as notebook (or in python console), it is the interface (usually ipython) which print the return value of last command.